# How to make private hashmap in one class visible to other class

Tags: java, hashmap

So everything works great in my program, but I read that making variable not private in class is a big mistake, because it can make problems with others part of big program.

Well I tried making HashMap airplane and flight private but I get error that "The field Airplane.airplane is not visible",which is of course true.

But how do I then make it visible in interface class?

Thanks in advance, I'm still learning and I got to this part in course.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
      Scanner imeskanera = new Scanner(System.in);
      Airplane airplane = new Airplane();
      flight flight = new flight();
      
      interface_aerodrom ui = new interface_aerodrom(imeskanera,airplane,flight);
      
      ui.start();
    }
}
```

/ Airplane class

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Airplane {
     HashMap<String,Integer>airplane;
    private String id;
    private int capacity;
    
    public Airplane() {
        this.airplane = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    }
    
    
    public void add(String id, int capacity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.airplane.put(id, capacity);
        
    }
    public String id() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public int capacity() {
        return this.capacity;
    }

    public String airplaneinfo() {
        return this.id + "( " + this.capacity + " )";
    }
}
```

/interface class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class interface_aerodrom {
    private Scanner imeskanera;
    private Airplane airplane;
    private flight flight;

    
    
    public interface_aerodrom(Scanner scanner, Airplane airplane,flight flight) {
        
        this.imeskanera = scanner;
        this.airplane = airplane;
        this.flight = flight;
    }
    
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Airport panel\r\n"
                + "--------------------");
        System.out.println();
        
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Choose operation:\r\n"
                    + "[1] Add airplane\r\n"
                    + "[2] Add flight\r\n"
                    + "[x] Exit");
            
            String input = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            input = input.trim();
            
            if(input.equals("x")) {
                flight_service();
                break;
            }
            else if(input.equals("1")) {
                addairplane();
            }
            else if(input.equals("2")){
                addflight();
            }
            
        }
        }
        
        
        
        public void flight_service() {
            System.out.println("Flight service\r\n"
                    + "------------");
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Choose operation:\r\n"
                        + "[1] Print planes\r\n"
                        + "[2] Print flights\r\n"
                        + "[3] Print plane info\r\n"
                        + "[x] Quit");
                String input = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
                input = input.toLowerCase();
                input = input.trim();
                if(input.equals("quit")){
                    break;
                }
                else if(input.equals("1")) {
                    for(String name : this.airplane.airplane.keySet()) {
                        int numberofseats = this.airplane.airplane.get(name);
                        String list = name + "( " + numberofseats + " )";
                        System.out.println(list);
                        
                    }
                }
                else if(input.equals("2")){
                    for(String name : this.flight.flight.keySet()) {
                        String value = this.flight.flight.get(name);
                        String list = name + value;
                        System.out.println(list);
                }
                }
                else if(input.equals("3")) {
                    System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
                    String planeid = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
                    if(airplanecontains(planeid)) {
                        int numberofseats = this.airplane.airplane.get(planeid);
                        System.out.println(planeid + "( " + numberofseats + " )" );
                        
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("That plane is not in our database");
                    }
                }
                        
                
            }
        }
    
        public void addairplane() {
            System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
            String ID = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Give plane capacity: ");
            int capacity = Integer.parseInt(this.imeskanera.nextLine());
            this.airplane.add(ID, capacity);
            
}       
        
        public boolean airplanecontains(String ID) {
            if(this.airplane.airplane.containsKey(ID)) {
                return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
            
        }
        
        public void addflight() {
            System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
            String ID = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
            if(airplanecontains(ID)) {
                System.out.println("Give departure airport code: ");
                String departure = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Give destination airport code: ");
                String destination = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
                int seats = this.airplane.airplane.get(ID);
                this.flight.flight.put(ID + " ( " + seats + " ) ",departure + "-" + destination);
                
                    }
            else {  
                System.out.println("This plane is not in our database");
            }
                }
                
            
            
            
            }
```

/ flight class

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class flight {
    HashMap<String,String>flight;
    
    public flight() {
        this.flight = new  HashMap<String,String>();
    }
    public void add(String departure, String destination) {
        this.flight.put(departure, destination);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You really need to follow naming conventions to begin with. Looking at your goal, `protected` looks suitable, but for this, Airplane needs to be extended in your subclasses to make the map accessible.

Comment: What's the problem with providing getters  for the hashmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a field private does not necessarily mean you can't share it. You can use a getter to return the `HashMap`.

```
private Map<String,Integer>airplane = new HashMap<>();

public Map<String,Integer> getAirPlaneMap() {
    return airplane;
}
```

The reason being is that this hides implementation details and allows for future changes without affecting users of the class.  Users don't need to know where the map comes from within your class. You could have retrieved it from some where yourself and the user wouldn't know.

You may also want to ensure a user can't change it. So you could do the following:

```
public Map<String,Integer> getAirPlaneMap() {
    return Collections.unModifiableMap(airplane);
}
```

The above will prevent the user from adding or deleting map elements.  But it won't prevent them from changing a retrieved object from the map unless that object is also immutable.

In general, setter and getters are the best way to allow users to `set and retrieve values`.  And it is usually a good idea to make defensive copies of mutable items that they are retrieving to ensure that the retrieved values are consistent for all users during execution of the program.